# unexcept return value when C++ call python

Tags: python, c++

python:

```
def add(a,b):
     print "in python func"
     print "ret = "+ str(a+b)
     return (9,3,'232')
```

C++

```
PyObject* pyRet = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs); 
int i,j;
const char* buf=NULL ;  
if (PyArg_ParseTuple(pyRet,"(iis)",i,j,&buf))
{
    printf("ERROR");
    return NULL;
}

printf("in c++, ret is :%d,%d,%s\n",i,j,buf);
```

```
---import sys---
---------------------- in python func ret = 9999 in c++, ret is :-1210380300,-1208982128,(null)
```

why return this value?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the values of `i` and `j`, you probably want `&i`, `&j`.

Edit: I think your result is a [PyTupleObject](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/tuple.html), so try something like the `PyTuple_GetItem()` function.

All the documentation I've been able to find on `PyArg_ParseTuple` seems to be related to passing arguments *to* methods rather than unpacking results.

Comment: still not return the right value:(PyArg_ParseTuple(pyRet,"(iis)",&i,&j,&buf)) ret is :-1080706840,-1211345131,(null)

Comment: How about if you use `iis` instead of `(iis)`?

Comment: return NULL, don't know why.  goto :  printf("ERROR");